# What is correct, when or while

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

What is correct usage of 'while'?
Is it correct to use 'while' here?

> Please consider the day and timing **while/when** you expect me to respond on call.

Comment: 'While' is not correct here. It might be more usual to say, *Please choose (decide on) a day and a time you would like me to call.*

Comment: Please could you explain why cant we use while here?

Comment: We use _while_ when speaking of something that happens at the same time that something else is going on. "The telephone rang while I was in the bathroom." - "Please wait while I fasten my shoe."

Answer (score 1):

"**While**", when used as a conjunction, means *during*.

If you use 'while' in your example, that would mean that you are asking the person to consider the day and timing **at the same time** they expect you to respond. I don't believe that is what you are trying to say.

I think you are trying to say that, **when** waiting for you to respond to a call, they should consider the day and time, because that will have a bearing on how quickly you respond.